# How to replace pandas plot xticks with days?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I've got a pandas hist plot like shown below. As you can see the xticks are currently set to 0-6 (Sunday - Saturday). I'd like to replace the tick label to the actual days so the days are showing instead of numbers.
0 - Sunday
1 - Monday
2 - Tuesday
3 - Wednesday
.
.

```
ax_by_day = df['Day Of Week'].hist(bins=7, alpha=0.5, figsize=(10,6), edgecolor='black')
ax_by_day.set_xticks(list(range(0,7,1)))
ax_by_day.set_xlabel('Day')
ax_by_day.set_ylabel('No. of Processes Executed')
```

I believe there's a way to map the xticks to new labels but surprisingly I'm unable to find details. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You need `.hist(bins=np.arange(-0.5,7), ...)` to cope with the discrete values.  And then `ax.set_xticklabels(['Sunday','Monday',...])`.

Comment: Not sure what you use to get the number for day of the week, but if it's pandas, pandas also has `.dt.day_name()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one of the many useful features of [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/calendar.html):

```py
import calendar
days = calendar.day_name
ax_by_day.set_xticklabels(days[6:] + days[:6])
```

Comment: edited and removed `list` because I had missed the rotation to start from Sunday

Comment: thanks @GuillaumeAnsanay-Alex. Worked nicely. Just didn't include the Sunday label at the end. I assume this is dropped off because of the spacing issue. I'll try and tilt it.